# Formatar CSS com PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Olá

Eu estou exibindo um conteudo HTML com formatação em CSS utilizando o print_r do PHP, mas estou com duvida quando as aspas simples, eu abri o STYLE com aspas simples, mas dentro da seleção da imagem tem 2 aspas simples tambem, mas não esta funcionando, como eu formato isso corretamente ?

```
<?php print_r("<div value='6_1' style='background-image: url('../img/banner-product.png')'></div>"); ?>
```

Comment: tenta usar echo em vez de print_r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso não é necessário colocar o caminho url com aspas pode ficar simplesmente `url(../img/banner-product.png)`, ficando:

```
print_r("<div value='6_1' style='background-image: url(../img/banner-product.png)'></div>");
```

outra forma, também poderia ser:

```
print_r('<div value="6_1" style="background-image: url(../img/banner-product.png)"></div>');
```

Mas também se pode escapar as aspas da seguinte forma, `\"` ou `\'`, dependo de como se envolve a string, o seja se é com aspas duplas ou simples.
Exemplo:

```
print_r("<div value='6_1' style='background-image: url(\"../img/banner-product.png\")'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Não seria algo com `\"` ?

```
<?php print_r("<div value='6_1' style='background-image: url(\"../img/banner-product.png\")'></div>"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o caractere de scape: \'
Use o seguinte código:

```
<?php echo '<div value="6_1" style="background-image: url(\'../img/banner-product.png\')"></div>'; ?>
```